# Add Print as pdf option in web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to print the image shown below as a PDF by providing a print option on my web page, I have the image path and other details that I want in the pdf such as date, description etc on the database. I want to print the image by providing the URL and details that I can get from the database.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I looked at jspdf . I'm not finding anything specific to my requirement.

Comment: Why are people demotivating me by down voting?? I tried searching for answers.

Comment: so at least post what you've searched so far, so that someone can put you in a right direction...

Comment: It would be helpful if someone who is experienced to atleast help me by telling what to look for instead.

Comment: @Praveen you need to show any existing code you have written to try out the problem. Open ended solutions cannot be provided like this. That's the reason for people downvoting, as the question indicates no existing effort from your side.

Comment: tell us a little about your server config where this site is hosted

Comment: @kenzotenma, the site is hosted on 000webhost , Apache server , PHP and mysql support

Comment: so you just wanna be able to have a function to which you can provide your image link and it will convert into a pdf file

Comment: have you looked into `fpdf` library

Comment: it's fairly simple to use: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/pdf-image.php

Comment: @kenzotenma, thank you , I will try this.

Comment: did you get any chance to achieve it with the answer above?

Comment: taking @kenzotenma 's suggestion i tried this
case "print" :
                if(isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
                ob_start();
                //$src= $certificate[$_SESSION["counter"]][4] ;
                require('./fpdf181/fpdf.php');
                $pdf = new FPDF(); 
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->Image('./android/certificate2.jpg',0,0);
                $pdf->Output();
                ob_clean();
                }
but i get this error, Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file.

Comment: i'm sorry , the text got wrapped , and i want to echo $src as the image source, for time being i have given an existing path

Comment: since you want your users to be able to take a print out of the generated pdf, you should go for `jspdf`. it would be a little easier to integrate. you should be able to send image data from server to client. and on client side, you can implement `jspdf` the way @BenjaminCaure suggests

Answer (score 1):

[jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/examples/basic.html) seems to be ok for your requirements, you can build pdf file containing image. It is quite simple in fact :

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

The only problem here from my understanding is that your have to get image from url then convert it to base64.

Here is a working solution :

https://codepen.io/bcaure/pen/OEVyKB

```js
var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open('GET', 'https://gravatar.com/avatar/09e327bdf4e6fc03bdda0fbaccf18132', true);
xmlHTTP.responseType = 'blob';
xmlHTTP.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(xmlHTTP.response);
    reader.onload =  function(url){
        var doc = new jsPDF(); 
        doc.addImage(url.target.result, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
        doc.save('two-by-four.pdf');
    };
};
xmlHTTP.send();
```

Comment: I just want to add [file reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is another easy way to create a data url of the image.

Comment: I have the URL for the image and other details that I want to include in the PDF in the database itself,  do I need AJAX or is there a PHP solution?

Comment: sure you can get pdf data from PHP, let's have a look to https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp